# What should the new description of the site be?

Tags: discussion, scope

More than one year ago, a question was asked here in order to define the new description for our site [What should the AI.SE Site Description be?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1430/2444). I think it's time to possibly revise the description of the site after having updated [the on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (based on the most upvoted answer to [this question](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615/2444)). The most upvoted answer, after a reasonable amount of time (1-2 weeks) will be used as the new description for our site. So, please, vote for the answer that contains the most next appropriate description of the site or the answer that says that the current description is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the current description of the site does not highlight certain important aspects of the site (e.g. AI history) and it contains redundant or noisy information.

In the current description of the site, the topics that I believe are redundant or noisy are

- mathematics (theory)
- discovery (theory/development),
- design (theory/development),
- practice (development),
- embedded uses (development),
- cognition (theory)
- policy (social)
- impact  (social)

So, here's my initial new proposal (based on the current first paragraph of the [new on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

> Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people interested in the **theoretical** (including mathematical), **philosophical, social, historical**, and *certain* developmental and academic aspects of artificial intelligence.

Maybe we could also explicitly mention "research"?

Comment: I might still include math explicitly.  *(i.e. people new to the field might not recognize that math in this context generally = theory.)*  New paragraph is much better.